# Customized Lazy minting NFTs on OpenSea

Tags: nft, opensea

Is it possible to implement customized lazy minting NFTs from scratch, and list them on OpenSea? I know that there are public smart contracts to lazy mint, but I'm not sure whether they can be listed on OpenSea.

Comment: I am having the same question. In the meanwhile, can you point me to those public smart contracts that help lazy mint? Thanks.